# Tableau data refresh query with the live and

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table connected Report A . that has approx 20 million rows of the since 2015 and generated 50000 of new rows every day it takes approx 25 mins of the extract to auto refresh every single day. in response to complain of client delayed data extracts on tableau server. Server admin decided to to set up 20 mins (refresh time) on all extracts effective Feb 28th. the result in the extracts to fail every single day in Report A. Please suggest What are my options to fix this and allow seamless refresh without touching/Reducing  the extract size.

Comment: Do you perform a full refresh every day, or an incremental refresh? If incremental, is the column you check against indexed?

Comment: I second Andy's question. It is critical to know whether you are doing a full refresh or an incremental one. (As the answer might be to switch to an incremental refresh if you're doing a full refresh currently.)

Comment: Hello Andy and Daniel perform a full refresh every day because I have to resolve the issue It has to be fix. Bug has to be removed pls help

Comment: I suggest you find some way to aggregate the data to make it smaller. Or make it a live connection. Extracting 20m rows especially if there are a lot of columns can overwhelm some systems.